# C++ brackets and formatting problems, (undeclared identifier, local function definitions are illegal)

Tags: c++, function, formatting

I am new to C++, I am trying to make a program that computes prime factors. My algorithms are mostly alright, but I don't know how to format functions properly, someone please help me clean up this mess

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getPrimeFactor(int);

int factor(int fisrt, int last)
{
int i = 0;

for  (i = fisrt; i <= last; i++)

    int getPrimeFactor(int n)
{
    if (i < 0)
        i = -i;

    // For i < 2; it is just i
    if (i < 2)
        return i;

    // otherwise, for an even number it is 2
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        return 2;

    // for other odd numbers, search for a divisor
    // until SQRT (n) [conceptual] n / div >= div is
    // equivalent to SQRT (n) >= div

    for (int div = 3; i / div >= div; div += 2)
    {
        // if div is a divisor, just return it.
        if (i % div == 0)
            return div;
    }

    // There is no divisor (n is prime), return it.
    return i;
    }


return 0;
}

int main()
{

int fisrtN; int lastN; int counter; int answer;
    cin >> fisrtN;
cin >> lastN;
answer = factor(fisrtN, lastN);
return(0);
cout << "Prime is" answer; "  ";
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to do formatting in your text editor?

Comment: Please ask a specific question and provide actual error messages with line numbers.

Comment: 1. Don't nest functions. 2. Don't put code after your `return` statement in `main()`.

Comment: the errors are;

line 13, error C2601: 'getPrimeFactor' : local function definitions are illegal

Comment: line 22 error C3071: operator '%' can only be applied to an instance of a ref class or a value-type

Comment: thank you carl norum for your response, may you please explain how to unnest my function?

I can't think of another way for the function to loop right with out it being there,

Comment: Then you should probably go get a beginner C++ book.

Comment: Define your GetPrimeFactor function before factor function and in the loop just call GetPrimeFactor(n).. also your factor function is declared to return an int, which according to the way you used it should be a prime factor but in the code you wrote it always returns 0

Answer (score 0):

You can not define the body of function inside the body of another one.

This is simplified version of your code with original indentation:

```
void getPrimeFactor(int);

int factor(int fisrt, int last)
{
...
for  (i = fisrt; i <= last; i++)

    int getPrimeFactor(int n)   // <-- illegal placement of function's definition
{
    ...
    return i;
    }
return 0;
}

int main()
{
...
return(0);          // <-- redundant line, 0 is return automatically
...                 // <-- code after return statement will never be executed
}
```

Note that indentation of your code really matters. The code that is hard to read is also hard to understand and more error prone ~> later it might cost you some time. Try to keep your code clean.

Also note that at the beginning you have declared the following prototype:

```
void getPrimeFactor(int);
```

but later in the code you have tried to define the function:

```
int getPrimeFactor(int n)
```